# fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) not returning a single value

Tags: php, pdo

When I use the code below I get `Undefined Index: email on $row['email']`. If I grab the whole array with `$row` and print_r, it displays like it should.
Where am i going wrong ?

```
            $stmt = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT email FROM $this->table WHERE `email`= :email");
            $stmt -> bindValue(':email', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()){
                 return $row['email'];
              }

$new = new Users;
 echo $new->reset_password($email);
}
```

Comment: `fetchAll` ... fetches all, use `fetch`

Comment: Since you are looping, you need `while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){` instead of `while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()){`

Comment: why you are selecting the same email you know already?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It is to check if the email entered in the db, then use mail() with it.

Comment: But why do you need to return it? Just return `true` or `false` depending on whether it's found.

Comment: to optimize your code you should just retrieve `email` instead of using `*` in your select

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fetchAll` returns a 2-dimensional array of all the results. To get just one row at a time, you should call `$stmt->fetch()`, not `$stmt->fetchAll()`.

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    ...
}
```

But since you're returning, you shouldn't use a loop at all. The `return` statement will terminate the loop after the first iteration. Just use an `if` statement.

```
if ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
    return $row['email'];
}
```

This whole code doesn't make much sense -- `$newemail` is guaranteed to be the same as `$email`, why are you returning it? It probably should be:

```
if ($stmt->fetch()) { // Email was found
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. What am doing is to check if it was found, then use the email in a mail().

Comment: Can't you use the original variable that you passed as the argument?

Comment: There I still would have to check if it existed in the database, then see if any row was returned, then send a password reset code

Answer (score 1):

to check if the email entered in the db,

```
$stmt = $db->dbh->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM $this->table WHERE email= ?");
$stmt->execute([$email]);
return $stmt->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use this code:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
    $newemail = $row['email'];             
}
```

Instead of this code:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetchAll()){
    $newemail = $row['email'];
}
```

Method `fetchAll()` fetches all rows in a single call, method `fetch()` fetches only current row and moves pointer to the next row.

Documentation to method `fetch()` can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) and documentation to method `fetchAll` can be found [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).